# react helper import fails in production but works in development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

I've got a file called "globalHelper.js" like this:

```
exports.myMethod = (data) => {
  // method here
}

exports.myOtherMethod = () => { ... }
```

and so on...

I import my Helper in other files like this:

```
import helper from "../Helper/globalHelper";
```

Now there is the problem:
In the past, everything worked with that when running my build-script:

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
```

but for some reason, when I run "npm run build", I get the error:

```
Attempted import error: '../Helper/globalHelper' does not contain a default export (imported as 'helper')
```

However, when I simply start my development server (npm start), everything works just fine.

I already tried to import like `import { helper } from "../Helper/globalHelper";`, but that did not work either.
Does someone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try exporting like this with ES6 syntax

```
export const myOtherMethod = () => { ... }
```

then

```
import { myOtherMethod } from '...your file'
```

The method you are using `exports.functionName` is CJS. you need to use require to get the methods.

> The CommonJS (CJS) format is used in Node.js and uses require and
> module.exports to define dependencies and modules. The npm ecosystem
> is built upon this format.

If you want to use module method you can do this.

```
export { myOtherMethod1, myOtherMethod2 }
```

then you import like this.

```
import * as Module from '....file name'
```

Comment: This actually helped: I changed my imports from `import * as helper from ../Helper/globalHelper` to `'const helper = require('../globalHelper.js')`.

Comment: would have been too good... now when I run my app in production I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`....

Comment: but still.... It only happens in production but not in development...

Comment: you need to use the method I provide, not module exports method. In development you are running it as a server, when you do npm run build, you are building static files. browser don't support CJS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Answer (score 2):

Since you've not `export default` you should import the function with `{}` like :

```
  import {helper} from "../Helper/globalHelper";
```

Comment: Problem is... I dont want to import a single method but my whole helper so that I can use "helper.myMethod" in other classes

Comment: Try out `import * as helper from '../Helper/globalHelper'`

Comment: @SnakeShadow what do you see when you do `import * as helper ...` and `console.log(helper)`

Comment: when I do that, I see an object of methods just as I want it to be. And as I said: It works in development but it fails when I do "npm build"

Comment: where did you find the details about the build command